# Progress bar in python to monitor copying tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil, tqdm

[image]

My question is I want a progress bar for my python script to check the progress of copying task.

Let's say I have a source folder inside that  I have a huge file that I want to copy in destination folder.

I am copying the file from source to destination using shutil.All I want a progress bar to monitor the progress .

I have tried tqdm but not getting any success yet.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the issue(s) you have encountered with tqdm?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile        I have created two directories 1)source folder (where my data is present) 2)destination folder(where i want to copy my data).What i want is a progress bar to  monitor how much data has been copied and how much time it will take to copy the data from source to destination.

Comment: Yes, I got that from your question, I was asking about your problems with tqdm specifically, since you state “I have tried tqdm but not getting any success yet.” Did you get some sort of error with tqdm?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile  No i did not get any errors while using tqdm.The problem is I dont know how to implement /use tqdm in my script.

Comment: Do you think you could edit your post to include a snippet of the relevant area in your code? Have you read the [tdqm docs](https://tqdm.github.io)?

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.copy()` is a "one-shoot" function. You won't be able to track the progress until you implement your own copy function such as in this link :

https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2015/05/12/file-copy-progress-window-with-pyqt-pyside-and-shutil/